# How to save the XML output of a Form POST?

Tags: xml, forms, file, api, post

Below is an example of my file on my www.MyExampleDomain.com domain.

When form button is submitted the browser refreshes and the browser window URL says www.XMLExampleDomain.com and the browser content has list of names in XML format.

How can I save that XML result to a .xml file on www.MyExampleDomain.com ?

myfile.htm

```
<HTML>
 <FORM METHOD="POST" ACTION="http://www.XMLExampleDomain.com">;
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="req" VALUE="api">
  <INPUT TYPE="HIDDEN" NAME="mode" VALUE="name_list">
  <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="api_key" VALUE="a234985929042a">DVD Comedy <br>
  <INPUT TYPE="RADIO" NAME="api_key" VALUE="s863950385433a">DVD Action <br>
  <INPUT TYPE="SUBMIT" VALUE="Click Here to List Names">
 </FORM>
</HTML>
```

Comment: It's up to your back-end code. What server side technologies you use ? Java/ASP/ASP.NET/PHP/Python/Node .etc. ?

Comment: I don't control XMLExampleDomain.com  It is not mine.  All I know is when I press the submit, it returns a list of names in XML format.  I can use html/Java/php/cgi/etc... on MyExampleDomain.com.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you don't control the target server which the form is posting to..

- Make the form post to your server
- Then post the form to www.XMLExampleDomain.com (from your server)
- get the result xml
- Save the xml data on your server
- and relay the response to the browser.

Comment: Thank you.  Can you direct me to some ideas/examples on how to "Make the form post on my server" ?

Comment: It depends on what language/technology you use. For example, in C# and ASP.NET, you can use HttpClient class to do this.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: So this is where it goes above my expertise. I only know html, some basic JavaScript, and .cgi.  MyExampleDomain.com is on HostGator.

Comment: @Sgooey Sounds like you really need to pick up some tutorials on web programming. That's really not something we can do for you here.

Comment: Can you suggest some specific websites where I can learn this?

Comment: Depends on what technology you want to start with... Today's popular web backends use C#, Java, Python, PHP and more. You'll have to do your research on which one you want to pick.